# document.querySelectorAll returns empty Nodelist with dynamic generated content

Tags: javascript, dom, nodelist, queryselector

I'm generating dynamic content while fetching data,once I generated the content I want to querySelect a card item in order to get its width,the problem is that I  get back an empty Nodelist. On the other hand if I try to query select the element on the console it works.
I even tried to run the code once the DomContent is loaded,but it does not work anyway. How come ?
Here's the code :

```js
const apiKey = "6d768187fc388a2008a76040f867388b";
const imageBaseUrl = "https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/original/";

function fetchData (url, callBack, optionalParameters) {
    fetch(url)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => callBack(data, optionalParameters));
}


const homePageSection =  [
    {
        title: "Upcoming Movies",
        path: "/movie/upcoming",
        shortTitle: "upcoming",
    },
    {
        title: "Trending Movies",
        path: "/trending/movie/week",
        shortTitle: "trending",
    },
    {
        title: "Top Rated Movie",
        path: "/movie/top_rated",
        shortTitle: "top-rated",
    },
];

homePageSection.forEach( (section,index) => { 

    const { title, shortTitle, path } = section;

    document.querySelectorAll("[meta-item-movie]")[index].innerHTML = title;

    let metaItemMovie = document.querySelectorAll("[meta-item-movie]");


    metaItemMovie[index].innerHTML += `
    <div class="${shortTitle}-movies meta-item flex flex-column relative" parent-slider parent-slider-home-page>
        <div class="slider-control__container overflow-hidden">
            <div class="slider-control__inner slider-wrapper flex relative" slider-wrapper slider-wrapper-home-page>
            
            </div>
        </div>    
        <div class="arrow-container flex flex-align-center flex-between" slider>
            <div class="arrow-left flex flex-center" arrow-left><span class="color-theme-white">&lharu;</span></div>
            <div class="arrow-right flex flex-center" arrow-right><span class="color-theme-white">&#8640;</span></div>      
        </div>  
    </div>
    ` 
    let pathUrl = `https://api.themoviedb.org/3/${path}?api_key=${apiKey}&language=en-US&page=1`;


    fetchData(pathUrl, ( { results }  ) => {
        results.forEach(result => {

            const {
                 backdrop_path,
                 release_date,
                 title,
                 vote_average,
                } = result
            
            let releaseDate = release_date.split("-").slice(0,1).join("");


            let link = document.createElement("a");
            link.setAttribute("href", "details.html");
            link.setAttribute("meta-item-card", "");
            link.classList.add("card");
            link.innerHTML = `
            <img src="${imageBaseUrl}${backdrop_path}" alt="${title}">
                    <p class="caption fs-200 fw-bold capitalize" meta-item-caption>${title}</p>
                    <div class="more-details flex flex-align-center">
                        <p class="year fw-bold fs-100">${releaseDate}</p>
                        <div class=" rating-container flex flex-center">
                            <img class="rating-image " src="../assets/details/star.png" alt="Star Rate">
                            <p class="rating-number fw-bold fs-100">${vote_average}</p> 
                        </div>
                    </div>  
            `;

            document.querySelectorAll("[slider-wrapper-home-page]")[index].appendChild(link);
        })
    })

})


// You'll see an empty list on the  console
console.log(document.querySelectorAll(".card"));
```

```css
/* "DM Sans", sans-serif; */

:root {

    /* ------- Color ------- */

    --theme-primary: hsla(349, 100%, 43%, 1);
    --theme-secondary: hsla(349, 100%, 35%, 1);
    --theme-logo: #bb1d24;
    --theme-navbar: #0f1115;
    --theme-white: #fff;
    --theme-black: #000;
    --theme-background: #1a1820;

 
    /* Font sizes */

    /* 35 - 75 px */

    --fs-600: clamp(2.19rem, 2.63vw + 1.53rem, 4.69rem); 

    /* 30 - 56 px */

    --fs-500:  clamp(1.88rem, 1.97vw + 1.38rem, 3.75rem);

    /* 65 px */

    --fs-400: clamp(1.5rem, 2.73vw + 0.82rem, 3rem);

    /* 48 px large screen || 24px small screen */

    --fs-300: clamp(1.5rem, 1.58vw + 1.11rem, 3rem);
    --fs-200: clamp(1.75rem, 0.26vw + 1.68rem, 2rem);
    --fs-150: clamp(0.94rem, 0.2vw + 0.89rem, 1.13rem);
    --fs-100: clamp(0.88rem, 0.13vw + 0.84rem, 1rem);

    /* font-families */

    --ff-dm-sans: "DM Sans", sans-serif;
}



/* Reset */

*,
*::before,
*::after {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box; 
}

body,
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
p,
figure,
picture {
    margin: 0;
}  

body {
    min-height: 100vh;
    line-height: 1.5;
    font-family: var(--ff-dm-sans); 
    overflow-x: hidden;
    background-color: var(--theme-background);
}

/* make images easier to work with */

img { display: block }

img,
picture {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
}

/* make form elements easier to work with */

input,
button,
textarea,
select, 
a,
li
{
    font: inherit;
    font-size: inherit;
}

li,a { 
    color: inherit;
    font-weight: inherit;
    text-transform: inherit;
}

a { text-decoration: none }

p { letter-spacing: inherit }

.fa { color: var(--theme-white) }

/* remove animations for people who've turned them off */


@media (prefers-reduced-motion: reduce) {
    *,
    *::before,
    *::after {
        animation-duration: 0.01ms !important;
        animation-iteration-count: 1 !important;
        transition-duration: 0.01ms !important;
        scroll-behavior: auto !important; 
    }  
}

input:focus { outline: none }

html:focus-within { scroll-behavior: smooth }  

ul { list-style-type: none }




/* ------------------- */
/*   Utility classes   */
/* ------------------- */ 

.flex { display: flex; gap: var(--gap, 1rem ) } 

.flex-column { flex-direction: column } 

.flex-center { align-items: center; justify-content: center } 

.flex-justify-center { justify-content: center }

.flex-around { justify-content: space-around }

.flex-between { justify-content: space-between }

.flex-align-center { align-items: center }

.grid { display: grid }

.grid-row-2 { grid-template-rows: 2fr 1fr }

.d-block { display: block }

.d-inline-block { display: inline-block }

.z-index-1 { z-index: 1; }

.relative { position: relative }

.fixed { position: fixed }

.reverse { order: -1 }

.pointer { cursor: pointer }

.overflow-hidden { overflow: hidden } 


.container {
    /* margin-inline: auto; */
    width: 100%;
    height: inherit;
    /* border: 1px solid blue; */
    z-index: 1;
    padding-inline: 2em;
}

.button-play {
    background-color: var(--theme-primary);
    width: max-content;
    padding: 0.5em 1em;
    border-radius: 0;
    border: none;
    transition: 300ms; 
}


/* Arrows */

.arrow-container {
    width: 100%;
}

.arrow-left,
.arrow-right { 
    padding-inline: clamp(0.5rem, 0.32vw + 0.42rem, 0.8rem);
    aspect-ratio: 1;
    transition: all 200ms linear;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: var(--theme-black);
    color: var(--theme-white);
}

[class*="arrow"] span {  font-size: 40px }

.arrow-left:hover span,
.arrow-right:hover span { color: var(--theme-primary); }

.button-play:hover { border-radius: 10px; background-color: var(--theme-secondary); }

.play-circle { width: 40px }

/* Card */

.rating { padding: 0.5em; background-color: var(--theme-black) }

/* Colors  */

.theme-white { color: var(--theme-white) }

.theme-logo { color: var(--theme-logo) }


/* Background Colors */

.theme-navbar { background-color:  var(--theme-navbar) }

.theme-background { background-color: var(--theme-background) }


/* Typography || "fs == font-size" */

.fs-100 { font-size: var(--fs-100) } /* 16px */
.fs-200 { font-size: var(--fs-200) } /* 32px */
.fs-300 { font-size: var(--fs-300) } /* 48px */
.fs-400 { font-size: var(--fs-400) } /* Clamp => {  [small] [medium] [large] => [24px][between these two][48px] } */
.fs-500 { font-size: var(--fs-500) } /* Clamp => {  [small] [medium] [large] => [30px][between these two][56px] } */
.fs-600 { font-size: var(--fs-600) } /* Clamp => {  [small] [medium] [large] => [35px][between these two][75px] } */

/* Letter Spacing */

.letter-spacing-1 { letter-spacing: 1px }
.letter-spacing-4 { letter-spacing: 4px }
.letter-spacing-8 { letter-spacing: 8px } 

/* Line Height */

.line-height-1 { line-height: 1.2; }
.line-height-2 { line-height: 1.4; }

/* Font Weight */

.fw-bold { font-weight: bold }

/* Text Style */

.uppercase { text-transform: uppercase }
.capitalize { text-transform: capitalize }

/* COLORS */

.theme-color-primary { color: var(--theme-primary) }
.theme-color-secondary { color: var(--theme-secondary) }
.theme-color-white { color: var(--theme-white) }
.theme-color-black { color: var(--theme-black) }


/* BACKGROUND COLOR */

.theme-bg-primary { background-color: var(--theme-primary) }
.theme-bg-secondary { background-color: var(--theme-secondary) }
.theme-bg-white { background-color: var(--theme-white) }
.theme-bg-black { background-color: var(--theme-black) }


/* GENERAL */

/* Navbar */

.theme-navbar { width: 100%; top: 0; left: 0; z-index: 1; }

.input-search-movies {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
    height: 80px;
    background-color: black;
    gap: 1rem;
    padding-inline: 1em;
    display: none;
}

.input-search-movies.active { display: flex }

.input-search-movies input { flex: 2; padding-block: 1em; transition: 300ms; }

.input-search-movies input:focus { background-color: var(--theme-black); color: var(--theme-white) }

.navbar { height: 80px } 

.search-icon__image { width: 40px }

/* Navbar Overlay */

.hamburger-menu-close { display: none }
.hamburger-menu-close.active { display: block }

.overlay {
    top: 80px;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    background-color: var(--theme-navbar);
    padding-inline: 2em;
    transform: translateX(-100%);
    transition: 300ms;
}

.overlay.active { transform: translateX(0); }

.overlay-list__genre-movies li,
.overlay-list__languages li,
.logo-tmdb { cursor: pointer; transition: 300ms; }

.overlay-list__genre-movies li:not(.caption):hover,
.overlay-list__languages li:not(.caption):hover { color: var(--theme-logo); font-size: 20px }

.logo-tmdb { object-fit: cover; margin-block: 0.5rem; width: 200px; }

/* Slider */

.slider { height: calc(100vh - 80px)  }

.poster-slider { height: 100% }

.poster-slider a { width: fit-content } 

.poster-slider__container .description { width: 80%; }


.poster-image { 
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: -1;
}

.rating-container { gap: 6px }

.rating-image { width: 18px }

/* Slider Control */

.slider-section { top: 80px }


.slider-control { flex: 1; height: 100%; }

.slider-wrapper { transition: 300ms }

.poster-slider { flex: 1 } 

.poster-slider__container .caption {  line-height: 1.2 }

.slider-control .slider-control__container { gap: 0 }

.slider-control__inner { width: 100%; gap: 10px }

.slider-control .card { flex: 1 0 calc(20% - 10px) }

.card { flex: 1 0 calc(10% - 10px) }

.card-image { height: 100% }


/* Section Slider */

.meta-item a {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: var(--theme-white);
}



/* Meta Items */

.meta-item-container { margin-block: 3rem }

.meta-item .card { flex: 1 0 calc(20% - 10px) }

.caption.active {
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Movie App Demo</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.1/css/all.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/media-queries.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/details-movie.css">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="#">
    <script type="module" src="../js/app/index.js" defer></script>
</head>
<body>
   

    <section>
        <div class="container meta-item-container flex flex-column">
            <p class="fs-500 fw-bold theme-white capitalize" meta-item-movie></p>
                 <!--  Js content here--  -->
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    <section>
        <div class="container meta-item-container flex flex-column">
            <p class="fs-500 fw-bold theme-white capitalize" meta-item-movie></p>
             <!-- Js content here -->
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    <section>
        <div class="container meta-item-container flex flex-column">
            <p class="fs-500 fw-bold theme-white capitalize" meta-item-movie></p>
            <!-- Js content here -->
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>

 
   
</body>
</html>
```

The card gets apppended but I cannot query select it.

Comment: The `.querySelector()` function *never* returns a node list. Perhaps you are thinking of `.querySelectorAll()`.

Comment: Can you add the relevant HTML and missing variables? You can use the snippet too `[<>]` to create a [mcve].

Comment: You should post a [mcve] as I took your code and created a test snippet and it worked just fine

Comment: To me it looks like `card` would be a duplicate reference to `link`.

Comment: Further to previous comments, your code works fine as written (demo: https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/1fetjxcg/1/); is your own code different in some way?

Comment: Is this actually how you use the code or is this just bits and pieces? Are you actually declaring **card** BEFORE actually adding anything to the DOM? If that is the case it will come back as NULL as nothing has been added.

Comment: I have just updated it, I also inserted the apikey since it is just a demo and I am practicing what I have been learning so far ( I am a newbie)

Comment: Ok I see the problem. Since you are fetching the data, your queryselector is being ran BEFORE fetch finishes. So it returns NULL as the fetch hasn't happened yet. There are many solutions to this problem and SO is actually filled with them too.

Comment: Solved ! I just chained the promise and then used the query selector, thanks !